# how to handle highlighting in Solrnet?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a problem in searching solr using solrnet client.. problem is when query with highlighting option on it gives me the count of highlights less than the actual results but when i search directly on solr admin page it gives same number of results in highlights is equal to number of rows specified. can i get the same number of results in highlights as number of rows specified in query?

Here is how i use highlighting in Solrnet

```
QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();

options.Rows = 20;
options.Start = 0;

HighlightingParameters hp = new HighlightingParameters();
List<string> fields = new List<string>();
fields.Add("Contents");
hp.Fields = fields;
options.Highlight = hp;

ISolrQueryResults<Document> results = solrWorker.Query(query, options);\\query is same as \\i commented before
```

and after this 
results.count!=results.Highlights.Count

results.count is exactly equal to options.Rows that is 20 but results.Highlights.Count is less than 20.

also one thing DocID is uniqueKey in schema.xml

i am using Solr 1.4.1 and SolrNet-0.2.3-net-2.0 and i have downloaded this version of Solrnet from http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/detail?name=SolrNet-0.2.3-net-2.0.zip&can=2&q=

And the problem i m facing is i have queried "+Contents:risk +(DocID:100)", now let this query matches 3 results now all these three results are shown but highlighting is done against only one of these results but when i see the admin page there all three results are shown as well as all three are highlighted.

Comment: please post the query as issued through the Solr admin, and a test case showing how you get highlights through SolrNet

Comment: here is the query i use in solr admin

"+Contents:risk +(DocID:1597599 DocID:1597431 DocID:1597698 DocID:1597711 DocID:1597239 DocID:1597282 DocID:1597296 DocID:1596981 DocID:1597317 DocID:1597556 DocID:1597613 DocID:1597399 DocID:1597768 DocID:1597458 DocID:1596909 DocID:1597442 DocID:1597292 DocID:1596930 DocID:1596948 DocID:1596967)"

and problem is admin page shows multiple highlights against single DocID (key) but solrNet shows only one.

Comment: The list of DocIDs doesn't matter. I need to know the *other* Solr parameters (i.e. the highlighting parameters, any filter queries, etc)

Comment: Also, how you are using SolrNet to get highlighting. Please add all that information to your question. Do not post as a comment.

Comment: what version of SolrNet are you using?

Comment: also, is the problem about *total* highlighting results, or highlighting snippets *per result*?

Comment: @Ahsan: please create an issue in http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/list and attach the files there.

Comment: @ Mauricio Scheffer: I got source code of solrNet and when i dive into the Code i saw one thing, it got every thing ok in xml but when the control goes in "ParseHighlighting" method, it creates a dictionary and add highlighting results in that dictionary and if some key already exist in dictionary it just modify value against that key. so in any case there would be only one value against one key.. but in the xml that is coming from solr there are more than one value agains one key.

Comment: I think type of Highlights in SolorQueryResults should be 
changed from IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>>> to List<Highlight> where Highlight is
class Highlight
{
string key;
IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> value;
}
what u say?

Comment: @Ahsan: please create an issue in code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/list and post your testcase there.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: i do that by attaching my index files but unfortunately it returned me an error, and i was unable to create an issue. might due to size of my index file is 44MB?

Comment: compress it to several chunks. e.g. a multi-part rar file.

Comment: did you try upgrading to 0.3.0b1 ? It has a fix related to highlighting snippets: http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/commit/d2f97e53e54a378e885540c8287ceefc1db6af96

Comment: Can u send be the web path of the binaries that contains this fix.

Comment: SolrNet 0.3.0b1 available here: http://solrnet.googlecode.com/files/SolrNet-0.3.0b1-net-2.0.zip

Comment: @ Mauricio Scheffer: I want to join u people as contributor can I do that? if ye then what is the way

Comment: join the google group http://groups.google.com/group/solrnet fork the code http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet and hack away!

Comment: it's an open source project, everyone can contribute.

Comment: did you try 0.3.0b1? did it fix your issue? otherwise please create the issue and attach your testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in SolrNet 0.2.3, [fixed](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/commit/d2f97e53e54a378e885540c8287ceefc1db6af96) in 0.3.0b1.